# How to use custom types for Retrofit @Query parameters?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Given the following [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) interface:

```
@GET("offices")
fun getOffices(@Query("uid") uid: String,
               @Query("lat") latitude: Double,
               @Query("lon") longitude: Double
): Call<List<Office>>
```

How can I replace the location parameters with a more user friendly `GeoLocation` type ...

```
data class GeoLocation(
        val latitude: Double,
        val longitude: Double
)
```

... which is automatically converted to `lat` and `lon` at request time such as:

```
@GET("offices")
fun getOffices(@Query("uid") uid: String,
               @Query("location") location: GeoLocation
): Call<List<Office>>
```

Here is the Retrofit setup:

```
fun createRetrofit(baseUrl: String,
                   okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
}
```

Comment: you can use interface default method and delegate to the older one, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Similar to but not duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510056/serialize-query-parameter-in-retrofit

Comment: @KirillRakhman Thank you for the link. What I don't understand is how can I use a `Converter<F, T>` to convert the `GeoLocation` object into `lat` and `lon` Double values.

Comment: It seems this isn't possible at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

If userfriendly access is your concern, you could just create a wrapper function. This way you don't have to mess with your Retrofit configuration at all

```
fun getOffices(uid: String, location: GeoLocation): Call<List<Office>> {
    return getOfficesIf(uid, location.lat, location.lon)
}

@GET("offices")
fun getOfficesIf(@Query("uid") uid: String,
                 @Query("lat") latitude: Double,
                 @Query("lon") longitude: Double
): Call<List<Office>>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell Retrofit2 doesn't allow not-annotated-functions on the interfaces it is supposed to implement, even if those functions have default implementations, which means this wrapper function needs to be in a separate class.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Query in suspend function as a parameter like that:

```
@GET("Posts")
suspend fun getPosts(@Query("MaxCount") maxCount: Int): Response<Posts>
```

Comment: how is this relevant to the question?